# Protractor test cases sporadically failing

Tags: angularjs, protractor

Automation test cases are sporadically failing. At times all the test cases are passing, and at times few are failing on Chrome and Firefox. Following Errors are present:

> Index out of bound.   Trying to access element at index: 1, but there
>   are only 0 elements that match locator By(css selector,
>   [ng-click="openMenu($mdOpenMenu, $event)"])�[39m

Element is not clickable at point (301, 315.6000061035156). Other element would receive the click:

I found following link on google as answer to my problem:http://www.blaiseliu.com/protractor-error-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-xx-xx/ 
 But Approach 2 and 3 might not be feasible as there are large number of elements clicked.

Please suggest.

Comment: Did you tried using browser.sleep or browser.wait ?

Answer (score 0):

This mean that you selecting an element that is not always in the current viewport and try to click on it.

You can solve it by the executeScript(element.scrollIntoView()).then(...